# Batch File to change Time Zones

Tags: batch-file, timezone

I have a simple batch job that I can't seem to get to work.  Want to be able to run the batch and change to the listed time zones in the batch job.  Could someone tell me what im doing wrong please?

```
@ECHO OFF
CLS
ECHO 1.Central
ECHO 2.Eastern
ECHO 3.Mountain
ECHO 4.Pacific
ECHO.

CHOICE /C 1234 /M "Select Time Zone:"
IF ERRORLEVEL 4 GOTO Pacific
IF ERRORLEVEL 3 GOTO Mountain
IF ERRORLEVEL 2 GOTO Eastern
IF ERRORLEVEL 1 GOTO Central

:Central
ECHO Central 
tzutil /s "Central Standard Time"
GOTO End

:Mountain
ECHO Mountain 
tzutil /s "Mountain Standard Time"
GOTO End

:Eastern
ECHO Eastern 
tzutil /s "Eastern Standard Time"
GOTO End

:Pacific
ECHO Pacific 
tzutil /s "Pacific Standard Time"
GOTO End

:End
```

Comment: Your code appears to run perfectly. What error messages are you getting? Why do you claim it fails?

Comment: I am not getting an error code.  When I run it, it does not change the temp zone on the computer

Comment: Perhaps you need to reboot before the timezone changes. (First time I've ever seen `tzutil` mentioned, anywhere).

Comment: works fine for me (Win11, non-admin, instant change (no reboot))

Comment: @cmacehwi - How are you observing that change?  Try something like `date /T & time /T & tzutil /g` at the end.  If you don't get the results you expected, please update your question to included the details.